# Can AdminUtils.createTopic API connect to multiple zookeeper nodes?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kafka-producer-api

I'm running into "replication factor: 1 larger than available brokers: 0 on a multi Node cluster" in the multi node kafka cluster, when trying to create topics using the createTopics function mentioned below. I have 3 kafka brokers, I'm trying to create 2 partitions per topic and keeping replication factor to 1. Not sure why getting this error. The same works perfectly fine in a single node setup (1 zookeeper and 1 kafka broker).

Any help would be much appreciated/

Error:

```
kafka.admin.AdminOperationException: replication factor: 1 larger than available brokers: 0
at kafka.admin.AdminUtils$.assignReplicasToBrokers(AdminUtils.scala:117)
at kafka.admin.AdminUtils$.createTopic(AdminUtils.scala:403)
at kafka.admin.AdminUtils.createTopic(AdminUtils.scala)
at io.confluent.examples.producer.ZookeeperUtil.createTopics(ZookeeperUtil.java:98)
at io.confluent.examples.producer.ProducerGroup.<init>(ProducerGroup.java:50)
at io.confluent.examples.producer.ProducerGroup.main(ProducerGroup.java:124)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:297)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)






private static final int DEFAULT_SESSION_TIMEOUT = 10 * 1000;
private static final int DEFAULT_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 8 * 1000;
private static final String ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT = "zNode01:2181,zNode02:2181,zNode03:2181";

/**
 * Opens a new ZooKeeper client to access the Kafka broker.
 */
private static ZkClient connectToZookeeper ()
{
    return new ZkClient(ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT,
                        DEFAULT_SESSION_TIMEOUT,
                        DEFAULT_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT,
                        ZKStringSerializer$.MODULE$);
}

/**
 * Given a ZooKeeper client instance, accesses the broker and returns
 * information about Kafka's contents.
 *
 * @param zookeeperClient A ZooKeeper client to access broker information
 *                        through.
 */
private static ZkUtils zookeeperUtility (ZkClient zookeeperClient)
{
    boolean isSecureCluster = false;
    return new ZkUtils(zookeeperClient, 
                       new ZkConnection(ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT),
                       isSecureCluster);
}


public static void createTopics (ArrayList<String> names, int partitions, int replication)
{
    ZkClient zkClient = connectToZookeeper();
    ZkUtils zkUtils = zookeeperUtility(zkClient);

try{
    for (String name: names)
    {
        if (existsTopic(name))
            continue;

        AdminUtils.createTopic(zkUtils, name, partitions, replication, new Properties(),RackAwareMode.Disabled$.MODULE$);

    }

} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (zkClient != null) {
        zkClient.close();
    }
}
}
```

I followed the following instructions to set up a multi node kafka cluster.

Setting a multi node Apache ZooKeeper cluster

On every node of the cluster add the following lines to the file kafka/config/zookeeper.properties

```
    server.1=zNode01:2888:3888
    server.2=zNode02:2888:3888
    server.3=zNode03:2888:3888
    #add here more servers if you want
    initLimit=5
    syncLimit=2
```

On every node of the cluster create a file called myid in the folder represented by the dataDir property (by default the folder is /tmp/zookeeper ). The myid file should only contains the id of the znode (‘1’ for zNode01, ‘2’ for ZNode02, etc… )

Setting  a multi broker Apache Kafka cluster

On every node of the cluster modify modify the property zookeeper.connect from the file  kafka/config/server.properties:

```
    zookeeper.connect=zNode01:2181,zNode02:2181,zNode03:2181
```

On every node of the cluster modify the property host.name from the file kafka/config/server.properties:
        host.name=zNode0x

On every node of the cluster modify the property broker.id from the file kafka/config/server.properties (every broker in the cluster should have a unique id)

Comment: all your kafka brokers are up in the set up ?

Comment: Yes they are all up!

Comment: Most likely your brokers aren't up, as @Knight71mentioned. Before you run your code, try creating a topic via kafka-topics.sh and produce to it via kafka-console-producer.sh.

Comment: I tried creating the topics from the terminal from one of the zookeeper nodes and it goes through fine, So im not sure whats going on ,, if i use the zookeeper.connect with one node it works. It gets into this only when i have mutiple zookeeper nodes in the Zookeeper.conenct property.

Comment: I have all my brokers and my kafka consumers up in all the 3 nodes, I would like to if AdminUtils.createTopic api, can connect to multiple zookeepers?

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that your brokers are not running, not that you aren't able to use multiple Zookeeper addresses for the client (yes, you can)

In newer versions of Kafka, you'd use `AdminClient` with `bootstrap.server`, not `zookeeper.connect`